# Capitalization of First Name and Last Name at Database end, while fetching from database or via PHP Functions after fetchin it from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Which one is the faster approach:

a) fetch first name and last name from database after capitalizing in required format at database end using database functions:

`SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(first_name, 2)), ' ', UPPER(SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(last_name, 2))) AS user_name FROM emp;`

```
<?php
$name = $user_name; // Robin Hood
```

or

b) fetch first name and last name from database, and then capitalize that using PHP functions.

`SELECT first_name, last_name FROM emp;`

```
<?php
$name = ucfirst($first_name).' '.ucfirst($last_name); // Robin Hood
```

Here are the time measurement, if I run both method in a for loop for 5000 times, just for the test of speeds.

(a)WITH DB
Start Time = 1298468915

### End Time =   1298468922

Diff = 7

(b)WITH PHP
Start Time = 1298468922

### End Time =   1298468930

Diff = 8

And here are more,

(a)WITH DB
Start Time = 1298469109

### End Time =   1298469115

Diff = 6

(b)WITH PHP
Start Time = 1298469115

### End Time =   1298469122

Diff = 7

And more,

(a)WITH DB
Start Time = 1298469293

### End Time =   1298469300

Diff = 7

(b)WITH PHP
Start Time = 1298469300

### End Time =   1298469307

Diff = 7

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you aren't doing this for performance, because this is the worst kind of optimization - the time it takes to even consider which is faster is longer than all of the cycles the faster one, whichever it is, would ever save, ever.

That said, it appears to me that the PHP method, with its single built-in function call, is probably superior to the MySQL method, and has the benefit of providing a much cleaner query as well.

Whatever you do, try to be consistent throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP provides a single function to do what you need and MySQL requires multiple function calls, I'd say that the PHP way is "faster". However, that eventual gain is so little that you couldn't even reliably benchmark it.
I suggest that you focus on other things in your code, database schema, DBMS configuration etc. that have much heavier impact on the performance of your application.